# inconsistent axes formatting with matplotlib subplots

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm unable to create subplots which respect the desired number of bins and tick structure. In the example below

```
# Figure
fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2,figsize=(fig_size2_x,fig_size2_y))

#ax1
ax1.set_xlim([0, 16])
ax1.set_ylim([1e-4, 1e0])
ax1.set_xlabel('$r$')
ax1.set_ylabel(r'$||\mathrm{Ham}||$')
ax1.locator_params(axis='x', nbins=4)
ax1.locator_params(axis='y', nbins=4)
ax1.grid(zorder = 0, color = col_gray1)

#ax1_line1,   = ax1.semilogy(r_1,   ham_1,   c = col1, zorder = 3, linestyle = 'solid',  label = r'l = 1')
#ax1_line2,   = ax1.semilogy(r_2,   ham_2,   c = col1, zorder = 3, linestyle = 'solid',  label = r'l = 2')
ax1_line3,   = ax1.semilogy(r_3,   ham_3,   c = col1, zorder = 3, linestyle = 'solid',  label = r'l = 3')
ax1_line4,   = ax1.semilogy(r_4,   ham_4,   c = col1, zorder = 3, linestyle = 'solid',  label = r'l = 4')
ax1_line5,   = ax1.semilogy(r_5,   ham_5,   c = col1, zorder = 3, linestyle = 'solid',  label = r'l = 5')
ax1_line6,   = ax1.semilogy(r_6,   ham_6,   c = col1, zorder = 3, linestyle = 'solid',  label = r'l = 6')
ax1_lineamr, = ax1.semilogy(r_amr, ham_amr, c = col2, zorder = 3, linestyle = 'solid',  label = r'l = \mathrm{amr}')

#ax2
ax2.set_xlim([0, 16])
ax2.set_ylim([1e-5, 1e-1])
ax2.set_xlabel('$r$')
ax2.set_ylabel(r'$||\mathrm{Mom_z}||$')
ax2.locator_params(axis='x', nbins=4)
ax2.locator_params(axis='y', nbins=4)
ax2.grid(zorder = 0, color = col_gray1)

#ax2_line1,   = ax2.semilogy(r_1,   mom_z_1,   c = col1, zorder = 3, linestyle = 'solid',  label = r'l = 1')
#ax2_line2,   = ax2.semilogy(r_2,   mom_z_2,   c = col1, zorder = 3, linestyle = 'solid',  label = r'l = 2')
ax2_line3,   = ax2.semilogy(r_3,   mom_z_3,   c = col1, zorder = 3, linestyle = 'solid',  label = r'l = 3')
ax2_line4,   = ax2.semilogy(r_4,   mom_z_4,   c = col1, zorder = 3, linestyle = 'solid',  label = r'l = 4')
ax2_line5,   = ax2.semilogy(r_5,   mom_z_5,   c = col1, zorder = 3, linestyle = 'solid',  label = r'l = 5')
ax2_line6,   = ax2.semilogy(r_6,   mom_z_6,   c = col1, zorder = 3, linestyle = 'solid',  label = r'l = 6')
ax2_lineamr, = ax2.semilogy(r_amr, mom_z_amr, c = col2, zorder = 3, linestyle = 'solid',  label = r'l = \mathrm{amr}')
```

the following output is created:[image]

It doesn't respect the desired number of x ticks (or y ticks in the second subplot) and the subticks are completely missing from the second subplot. If I change the y limits on the second subplot to match the first however,

```
# Figure
fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2,figsize=(fig_size2_x,fig_size2_y))

#ax1
ax1.set_xlim([0, 16])
ax1.set_ylim([1e-4, 1e0])
ax1.set_xlabel('$r$')
ax1.set_ylabel(r'$||\mathrm{Ham}||$')
ax1.locator_params(axis='x', nbins=4)
ax1.locator_params(axis='y', nbins=4)
ax1.grid(zorder = 0, color = col_gray1)

#ax1_line1,   = ax1.semilogy(r_1,   ham_1,   c = col1, zorder = 3, linestyle = 'solid',  label = r'l = 1')
#ax1_line2,   = ax1.semilogy(r_2,   ham_2,   c = col1, zorder = 3, linestyle = 'solid',  label = r'l = 2')
ax1_line3,   = ax1.semilogy(r_3,   ham_3,   c = col1, zorder = 3, linestyle = 'solid',  label = r'l = 3')
ax1_line4,   = ax1.semilogy(r_4,   ham_4,   c = col1, zorder = 3, linestyle = 'solid',  label = r'l = 4')
ax1_line5,   = ax1.semilogy(r_5,   ham_5,   c = col1, zorder = 3, linestyle = 'solid',  label = r'l = 5')
ax1_line6,   = ax1.semilogy(r_6,   ham_6,   c = col1, zorder = 3, linestyle = 'solid',  label = r'l = 6')
ax1_lineamr, = ax1.semilogy(r_amr, ham_amr, c = col2, zorder = 3, linestyle = 'solid',  label = r'l = \mathrm{amr}')

#ax2
ax2.set_xlim([0, 16])
ax2.set_ylim([1e-4, 1e0])
ax2.set_xlabel('$r$')
ax2.set_ylabel(r'$||\mathrm{Mom_z}||$')
ax2.locator_params(axis='x', nbins=4)
ax2.locator_params(axis='y', nbins=4)
ax2.grid(zorder = 0, color = col_gray1)

#ax2_line1,   = ax2.semilogy(r_1,   mom_z_1,   c = col1, zorder = 3, linestyle = 'solid',  label = r'l = 1')
#ax2_line2,   = ax2.semilogy(r_2,   mom_z_2,   c = col1, zorder = 3, linestyle = 'solid',  label = r'l = 2')
ax2_line3,   = ax2.semilogy(r_3,   mom_z_3,   c = col1, zorder = 3, linestyle = 'solid',  label = r'l = 3')
ax2_line4,   = ax2.semilogy(r_4,   mom_z_4,   c = col1, zorder = 3, linestyle = 'solid',  label = r'l = 4')
ax2_line5,   = ax2.semilogy(r_5,   mom_z_5,   c = col1, zorder = 3, linestyle = 'solid',  label = r'l = 5')
ax2_line6,   = ax2.semilogy(r_6,   mom_z_6,   c = col1, zorder = 3, linestyle = 'solid',  label = r'l = 6')
ax2_lineamr, = ax2.semilogy(r_amr, mom_z_amr, c = col2, zorder = 3, linestyle = 'solid',  label = r'l = \mathrm{amr}')
```

I get:[image]

I'd Like to create subplots with 4 x bins (ticks at 0, 4, 8, 12, 16) and 4 y bins (ticks every factor of 10) with subticks. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

On the x axis, try `set_xticks` instead of `locator_params`. For y axis, just `set_yscale` instead of `locator_params` too:

```
xbins = 4
xticks = np.linspace(0, 16, xbins+1)

ax1.set_xticks(xticks)
ax1.set_yscale('log')

ax2.set_xticks(xticks)
ax2.set_yscale('log')
```

[image]

Note: If you use `set_yscale`, maybe you can use the `plot` instead of `semilogy`. Example:

```
ax1_line3, = ax1.plot(r_3, ham_3, c=col1, zorder=3, linestyle='solid', label=r'l = 3')
```